# Filter by votes in a determined period with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, filtering, aggregate

I have users with votes indexed as follows

```
{
 id: 1
 name: John
 votes: [
   {
    id: 1
    created_at: 2015-01-01T15:50:59.000+02:00
   },
   {
    id: 2
    created_at: 2015-02-15T18:42:30.000+02:00
   },
   {
    id: 3
    created_at: 2015-02-22T02:06:15.000+02:00
   }
 ]
},
{
 id: 2
 name: Mark
 votes: [
   {
    id: 1
    created_at: 2015-02-10T08:18:20.000+02:00
   }
 ]
}
```

And I would like to filter users by the number of votes in a determined period, for example with the users who have been voted twice in the last month I would get only John.

I know how to get the users voted in the last month

```
{  
   "filter":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "range":{  
                  "user.votes.created_at":{  
                     "from":"now-1M"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

But I don't know how I could aggregate the votes for each document and filter by it. Or maybe there is other mechanism that I could use.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter the result by the result of an aggregation like `GROUP BY ... HAVING ...` in SQL, then (as far as I know) Elasticsearch can't help you with that... yet. You would have to do that logic application-side. See [Issue #4404 on Elasticsearch GitHub](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4404)

But a query to aggregate the number of votes for each user could look something like this:

```
{
    "query":{
        "filtered":{
            "filter":{  
                "bool":{  
                    "must":[  
                        { "range":{  "user.votes.created_at":{ "from":"now-1M" } } }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        //A bucket for each user ID
        "users": { "terms"  : { "field" : "user.id" } },
        //Aggregate the number votes for each user
        "aggs" : { 
            "num_votes" : { "value_count" : { "field" : "user.votes.created_at" } }
        }
    }
}
```